# Как поменять цвет изменений в intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

Можно ли в Intellij Idea изменить цвет вертикальных полос которые показывают изменения рядом с номером строки (скрин)? Нашел только как менять цвета при решении конфликтов, но это не то.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

там чуть ниже есть VCS (Version Control System) меню - вот в нем и надо менять
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]